# Proper way to define templated constant without C++14?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, constants

I would like to define custom constants which can be used for an arbitrary type (e.g. `float`, `double`, etc.). As an example, suppose I wish to define a constant whose value is pi.

The obvious solution is to use `#define pi 3.14159265359`, but then `pi` would not be in a namespace and I risk a name collision. I'm not using C++14 so I can't use a [variable template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Variable_templates). The best way I can think to do this is like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace constants {
    template<typename T> T pi() {
        return 3.14159265359;
    }
}

int main() {
    float pitest = 0;
    pitest = constants::pi<float>();
    cout << pitest << endl;
    cout << constants::pi<long double>() << endl;
    cout << constants::pi<int>() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I can now define these constants within a namespace and I can use an arbitrary (numerical) type as desired. However, there are at least two undesirable features of this:

1. It requires a function call which should not be necessary (it's just a constant!).
2. I have to specify the type in the function call, even if the function is returning to a variable of known type. For example, in the above code I have to use `pitest = constants::pi<float>();` rather than simply `pitest = constants::pi();` even though `pitest` is obviously a `float`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a special object with automatic conversion to any type?

```
static struct {
    template<class T> operator T() const constexpr
    { return (T)3.14159265359; }
} pi;
```

You might even add specializations for bigger types, arbitrary-precision-arithmetic, formula-systems, whatever.

Answer (score 2):

```
static struct { template<class T> operator T() const constexpr { return 3.14; } } pi;
```

is the first step.

```
template<class T> struct type {};
template<class T> constexpr T get_pi( type<T> ) { return 3.14; }
static struct { template<class T> operator T() const constexpr { return get_pi( type<T>{} ); } } pi;
```

is the second type -- now you can add new overloads for new types without having to specialize.  All `pi` does is do the magic casting.

Sadly, this requires that we match the type exactly -- a new overload for `int` won't solve `long`, or a new overload for `double` won't solve `float`.

But this is C++, we can do it!

```
template<class T> struct contra_type {
  constexpr contra_type(contra_type&&) {};

  template<class U, class=typename std::enable_if< std::is_convertible< T, U >::value >::type>
  constexpr contra_type( contra_type<U>&& ) {}
};
template<class T> constexpr auto get_pi( type<T>, ... )->decltype(T(3.14)) { return T(3.14); }
static struct { template<class T> operator T() const constexpr { return get_pi( contra_type<T>{} ); } } pi;
```

is the next step.  Now we can add overloads for `get_pi( type<bignum> )` and such and have it work.  In fact, anything implicitly convertable from `bignum` will call `get_pi( type<bignum> )` automatically.

Not sure how to enable ADL -- if I take a `T*`, I'll get covariant overloads not contravariant overloads (and as we are actually overloading on return type, that isn't want I want).

`contra_type<U>` is convertible to `contra_type<T>` if and only if `T` is convertable to `U`.  This means that `pi_func( contra_type<Foo>{} )` will attempt to find a `pi_func` that takes a type that can convert to `Foo`, and call that instead.

The `...` overload gives us a default implementation that matches everything exactly, but because it has `...` it will be preferred to call any other function instead of it that matches.

Comment: This is a bit overkill for my intended use of these constants, but +1 for going above and beyond.

Comment: @Null there is no kill like overengineering.